# How does flying twitter bird work

Tags: twitter

I came across this link [flying twitter bird](http://www.cashdove.com/2012/03/how-to-add-flying-twitter-bird-to-your.html) , was just wondering , how does this work.When we scroll the page it flies and when we stop scrolling it rests somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a peace of javascript. Scroling is an event that triggers an action. The script is searching for block-elements on the screen and gets their top-offset. Then an animated gif is moved from its current position to the new position.

No magic, just simple javascript